# Use provider in streamBuilder

Tags: flutter, dart

When I use code below :
In audioService plugin

```
              StreamBuilder<ScreenState>(
                  stream: Rx.combineLatest3<List<MediaItem>, MediaItem,
                          PlaybackState, ScreenState>(
                      AudioService.queueStream,
                      AudioService.currentMediaItemStream,
                      AudioService.playbackStateStream,
                      (queue, mediaItem, playbackState) =>
                          ScreenState(queue, mediaItem, playbackState)),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    final screenState = snapshot.data;
                    return Consumer<AudioServiceSubscription>(
                      builder: (_, audioSubscription, ch) {
                        audioSubscription.setQueue(screenState?.queue);
                        audioSubscription.setMediaItem(screenState?.mediaItem);
                        audioSubscription
                            .setPlaybackState(screenState?.playbackState);
                        return ch;
                      },
                      child: _palyer(),
                    );
                  },
                ),
```

I get the error

```
setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
```

my provider class is

```
class AudioServiceSubscription with ChangeNotifier {
  List<MediaItem> _queue;
  MediaItem _mediaItem;
  PlaybackState _playbackState;

  List<MediaItem> get queue => _queue;
  MediaItem get mediaItem => _mediaItem;
  PlaybackState get playbackState => _playbackState;
  BasicPlaybackState get basicPlaybackState =>
      _playbackState?.basicState ?? BasicPlaybackState.none;

  void setQueue(List<MediaItem> queue) {
    _queue = queue;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setMediaItem(MediaItem mediaItem) {
    _mediaItem = mediaItem;
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void setPlaybackState(PlaybackState playbackState) {
    _playbackState = playbackState;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I think the reason I get error is that we can't use provider in builder of streamBuilder
And I don't know any idea that how to do this correctly?

Comment: Can u show your build method?

Comment: I am using the same approach which is in example of audio_service : ```https://github.com/ryanheise/audio_service/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart``` but instead of lines 107-110, I want to store them in my provider class to use the audio state in other routes of app

Comment: Did you try Consumer?

Comment: yes , I try that , but the issue is there .

Comment: I am sure the reason is that we can't use provider in builder of streamBuilder.but I don't find any alternative.if I comment notifyListeners in AudioServiceSubscription , the issue can be resolved but that's defiantly is not the solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can use provider in streambuilder buid we cannot set listenable value in it becouse before building UI we cannot set value which is listenable. We can also not use SetState() in it.